# How can I use a proxy in a tool that doesn't have proxy options?

Tags: proxy

I am using a command line tool that doesn't have proxy options, but I want to route its traffic through a proxy. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you want to route all your system's traffic through a proxy or just the command line tool's traffic?

Comment: Both options are fine

Answer (score 0):

You can set up NetworkManager to route your system's traffic through your proxy. Click on the NetworkManager icon, then "Edit Connections...",  select the network you're connected to and click the cog icon. From there, click on the tab "Proxy" and enter the proxy information.